# Finding the JavaScript Associated With a Certain Element

Tags: javascript, html

This seems to be impossible with the typical "inspect element" approach, which seems great for HTML and CSS, but that's it. I can't go to a particular element and then link to the particular JavaScript that's controlling it. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: What do you mean by "controlling it"?

Comment: Do you mean event handler bound to the element?

Comment: Whatever it is that's linking the element to js. That is, the element has something (usually an identifier/classname) mentioned in the js code. How can I link to that particular section of the js code, just like I can link to the particular section of the stylesheet for a particular element?

Comment: I either search for instance of the id or the classname(s) in the JS, or I look for attached event handlers. Naturally, there are many ways of targetting a particular element with JS that these methods dont catch - particularly when an element is being accessed based on it's relationship to another element, whether it be a sibling, parent or other.

Comment: Exactly. Strange no one's developed something to dynamically analyze JS in pages yet, especially with the sudden JS explosion of widespread use in recent years.

Comment: @TomBurns - yeah, but don't forget you can set a breakpoint that will fire whenever any of the following conditions are met: (1) Subtree modifications, (2) Attributes modifications (3) Node Removal. I don't really see anything that would motivate someone to create a tool that essentially provides the same capability, albeit in a _far_ more complex fashion. You'd have to be sniffing a _lot_ of other people's pages to even come close to saving the time required to make such a tool. I suspect, there's simply no demand/need for such a tool. Dunno.

Comment: No idea why this would be closed as "unclear what you're asking". It seems perfectly clear to me.

Answer (score 2):

As someone else said, there is no precise notion of "the JS controlling an element". There is JS which does something to an element, and there is JS which handles an event on a element. To handle these cases:

1. In Chrome devtools, select the element, right-click, and select `Break on...`. This will break when something happens to the element, such as a change in its children or its attributes, and leave you on the line that was making the modification.
2. Use "Event Listener Breakpoints" and choose to break on a particular event. Then initiate that event on an element which is listening for it, such as by clicking on the element. The debugger will take you to the line handling that event (which might be deep within jQuery, but that's another story).